# SQL statement structuring

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `AgentFare` and `SalesHeader` having `hdrGuid` and `hdrGuid` , `DocumentNumber` as columns respectively.
I have to perform a query based on Document number, however I am not able to figure out which of the two following queries are most suitable.

```
SELECT agf.Fare , agf.Tax . agf.Commission 
FROM AgentFare as agf 
  INNER JOIN SalesHeader as h ON agf.hdrGuid = h.hdrGuid AND h.DocumentNumber = 'XYZ'
```

OR

```
SELECT agf.Fare , agf.Tax . agf.Commission 
FROM AgentFare as agf 
   INNER JOIN SalesHeader as h ON agf.hdrGuid = h.hdrGuid
WHERE h.DocumentNumber = 'XYZ'
```

Which of the 2 are more appropriate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "ON" statement should be used to define on what columns 2 tables should be joined.
The "WHERE" statement is intended to filter your results.

The second option is the more appropriate to use.

Answer (score 2):

First method is more appropriate.Since it will take less time as compared to second query.

Comment: That is what i was asking about.Thanks @KT

Comment: Why do you think it will take less time?

Comment: See in first case you are joining the two table with all the filter you want.But in other case first you perform join and then you put one filter.So the second query will take more time.This is want I think.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server have a look at the execution plans. My guess would be there isn't much difference between the two. But that's a guess.

Comment: yeah if the table have less records then the difference will be negligible.But if you have more records in the table then i think the difference will be visible.

Answer (score 1):

You might find that this is a case of personal preference. My preference is for the second one. It's clear to me what you are joining on and what you are filtering with. If you change your code so that you replace 'XYZ' with a parameter, then for me the second way is much easier. I expect to find the 'filters' at the bottom.